# flutter exits Unexpectedly

Tags: android, dart, flutter

When I run flutter it will stops working. It shows "flutter exits unexpectedly" as error message.

github issues link: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16108

**I am using Parrot linux operating system.**

**

- **Terminal Output:**

**

```
─[✗]─[dracula@parrot]─[~]
└──╼ $flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.2.3, on Linux, locale C.UTF-8)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 27.0.3)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.1)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2018.1)
[✓] Connected devices (1 available)

• No issues found!

Oops; flutter has exited unexpectedly.
Sending crash report to Google.
Failed to send crash report due to a network error: SocketException: Failed host lookup: 'clients2.google.com' (OS Error: Temporary failure in name resolution, errno = -3)
Crash report written to /home/dracula/flutter_10.log;
please let us know at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues.
```

Comment: try setting LC_ALL & LANG environment variable as `en_US.UTF-8` & re run flutter-doctor ?

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

try `flutter upgrade` and then check `flutter doctor`

Comment: Everything is up-to-date. But it stops works. I don't know what the problem is

Comment: check out which channel you are using
`flutter channel`

Comment: Most of the time flutter quits unexpectedly due to connection error.Make sure the connection is on or reliable.

Answer (score 3):

Try apt-get update and upgrade first. You may need to use sudo
After that, run flutter doctor again.

Also, the error seems to suggest a network connectivity issue with 'clients2.google.com' so, please also check that your network connectivity is ok without blocking.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the time flutter quits unexpectedly due to connection error.Make sure the connection is on or reliable.I Think there is a network error.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the file that the crash report is written to. In your case it's at/home/dracula/flutter_10.log. You will find out exactly why it crashed.

Answer (score 2):

This is surely network problem. since flutter works mostly on the network make sure everything is fine on your network.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have something wrong with your network. Upgrade Flutter and try to use a VPN when you are using Flutter.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to make another new fresh project? If not please make a new one instead by entering this command `flutter create myapp` on your console/terminal and then enter its directory.

Attach your device or run the emulator by using `flutter emulators --launch *your_emu_device*` and then hit `flutter run`

If you still see the same error, try to **deleting** your SDK and re-download it.

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading dart version . RUn the following command .

```
 brew upgrade dart.
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Run command as an administrator or try creating the project on any other drive than C